# rel="nofollow" on randomly generated internal links

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, googlebot, nofollow

I have a section on a website where I show a list of posts from the past. The list is randomly generated and it's changing every time a page is loaded.

I was wondering, would it be better to add a rel="nofollow" to these links or not?
I'm worried that Google might think it's a strategy to have more keywords on the site and that content  displayed for search engines is different from the content I'm serving to "regular" users.. but then Matt Cutts says [he wouldn't add rel="nofollow"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SAPUx4Beh8) to internal links. What do you guys think?

Comment: I'd take Matt Cutts' advice

Comment: "a strategy to have more keywords on the site" - Why do you think so? Aren't these pages already on the site and linked to already someplace? "content displayed for search engines is different" - Again, why do you think so; unless it really is different? You've already stated it's random, so a regular user sees the same "random" content - do they not?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it does make sense. I was just overthinking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Showing random post from your site is a pretty common practice, adding `rel="nofollow"` to such links makes no sense at all because it goes against what `nofollow` really means.

`nofollow` just indicates that what you are posting is not endorsed by you (or that webpage), or there is a some kind of commercial relationship between that webpage and the link it specifies.

It would be better to clearly group that section with an *html* tag like the [aside](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-aside-element) element.